# How to prevent filtering after second date slider change?

Tags: r, shiny

Below is my observeEvent update options for a shiny app. A user can select a date range, which will then update the unique wildernesses available. The user can then select a wilderness which will update the available species in that wilderness. Then finally they can select a species and see which unique lake_ids are available to choose which will then get plotted.

My question is, how do I prevent the filtering from trickling down each option when I change the date range for the second time? So the user has chosen all their inputs. They then want to only adjust the date range keeping all the same inputs as first selected. However my script will reset all the ui options once the date is changed and the user has to walk through each selection again.

```
   bd_data <- data.frame(id = c(10008, 10008,10008), date = c(2018,2019,2020), 
                      species = c("ramu", "ramu", "ramu"),
                      wilderness = c("yosemite", "yosemite", "yosemite"), 
                      visual_life_stage = c("adult", "adult", "adult"),
                      bd = c(1,2,3) )



ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(8,
                    h1(strong("National Park Service App - RIBBiTR ")))),
    
    navbarPage("", inverse = T,
               
               tabPanel("Home", icon = icon("info-circle"),
                        fluidPage(
                          fluidRow(
                            h1(strong("Disclaimer"), style = "font-size:20px;"),
                            
                            column(12, p(""))),
                          
                          fluidRow(
                            h1(strong("Intended Use"),style = "font-size:20px;"),
                            
                            column(12, p(""))),
                          
                          fluidRow(
                            h1(strong("Data Collection"),style = "font-size:20px;"),
                            column(12, p(""))))),
               
               
               tabPanel(title = "Site Map", icon = icon("globe-asia"),
                        
                        sidebarLayout(
                          
                          sidebarPanel(
                            
                            sliderInput(inputId = "bd_date",
                                        label = "Select an annual range",
                                        min = min(bd_data$date), max = max(bd_data$date), 
                                        value =  c((max(bd_data$date) - 5), max(bd_data$date)),
                                        sep = ""),
                            pickerInput(inputId = "wilderness_2",
                                        label = "Select a wilderness",
                                        choices = unique(bd_data$wilderness),
                                        multiple = F,
                                        selected = ""),
                            pickerInput(inputId = "bd_species",
                                        label = "Select a species",
                                        choices = unique(bd_data$species),
                                        multiple = F,
                                        selected = "ramu"),
                            pickerInput(inputId = "stage",
                                        label = "Select a life stage",
                                        choices = unique(bd_data$visual_life_stage),
                                        selected = "adult",
                                        multiple = F),
                            pickerInput(inputId = "bd_id",
                                        label = "select site",
                                        choices = unique(bd_data$id),
                                        multiple = F)
                          ),
                          mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "bd_plots"))
                          )
               )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  bd_reac <- reactive({
    req(input$bd_date,input$wilderness_2,input$bd_species,input$stage,input$bd_id)
    bd_data %>% 
      dplyr::filter((date <= input$bd_date[2] & date >= input$bd_date[1]), 
                    wilderness == input$wilderness_2, species == input$bd_species, 
                    visual_life_stage == input$stage, id == input$bd_id)
    
  })
  
  ### I believe my error is occuring with the filtering or plotting of the data here or just above
  output$bd_plots <- renderPlot({
    req(bd_reac())
    ggplot(data = bd_reac(), aes(x = date, y = bd)) + 
      geom_point() + geom_line() +
      xlim(c(input$bd_date[1:2]))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$bd_date, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "wilderness_2", 
                      choices = unique(bd_data$wilderness[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2]]), 
                      selected = "yosemite")
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$wilderness_2, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "bd_species", 
                      choices = unique(bd_data$species[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                       & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2]))
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$bd_species, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "stage", 
                      choices = unique(bd_data$visual_life_stage[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                                 & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2 
                                                                 & bd_data$species == input$bd_species]))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$stage, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "bd_id",
                      choices = unique(bd_data$id[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                  & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2 
                                                  & bd_data$species == input$bd_species
                                                  & bd_data$visual_life_stage == input$stage]))
  })
  
}              

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of your app to see how it works? Thanks

Comment: emr2 just updated for a MRE app